# How to handle try-catch clause for imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(local_path));

Tags: android, imageview, try-catch, filenotfoundexception

I want to handle the case when an `imageView` tries to open an image from local files that was previously deleted by the user and display a default image instead. 
For this I try:

```
int flag = 0;
try{
        img_car.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path_picture));
        flag = 1;
    }
catch(Exception e){ //if I put FileNotFoundException I get error: Unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException. This exception is never thrown from the try 
// statement body
        Log.i("TAG EXCEPTION PIC", e.getMessage());
        img_car.setImageResource(pictureId);
    }
```

Both `img_car.setImageResource(pictureId);`  and  `img_car.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path_picture));`(when the picture physically exists) work.

My problem is that I can't catch the exception (when the picture does not exists), basically  this clause does not throw it.(My `LogCat` does not display any info log message). Even that, `LogCat` displays `java.io.FileNotFoundException`:

```
 09-06 13:12:22.066: W/ImageView(27274): Unable to open content:
 file:///storage/sdcard0/folder_name/my_image.PNG
 09-06 13:12:22.066: W/ImageView(27274): java.io.FileNotFoundException:
 /storage/sdcard0/folder_name/my_image.PNG: open
 failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) 09-06 13:12:22.066:
 W/ImageView(27274):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
 09-06 13:12:22.066: W/ImageView(27274):    at
 java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78) 09-06
 13:12:22.066: W/ImageView(27274):  at
 java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105) 09-06
 13:12:22.066: W/ImageView(27274):  at
 android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:445)
 09-06 13:12:22.066: W/ImageView(27274):    at
 android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:631) 09-06
 13:12:22.066: W/ImageView(27274):  at
 android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:379) 09-06
 13:12:22.066: W/ImageView(27274):  at
 com.myapp....
```

pointing me to the line: `img_car.setImageURI` . Another strange thing is that the flag has the value `1` after the `try-catch` is executed even the exception occours on the line above so theoretical this line shouldn't be executed.(right?). Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: just make sure image name must be there with that name....

Comment: @PiyushGupta This is the case I want to handle....when the image is not there (in files).This is what you mea, right?

Comment: ya.... but you can also do with different

Comment: @PiyushGupta I'm eager to hear your idea

Comment: you can check it with by your path also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I quit `using try-catch` and instead did this:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_picture);
            if(bitmap != null)
                imgdata.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else{
                imgdata.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.default_image));
            }
```

I extract first the content into a bitmap and if bitmap is null then load default image. It works.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this way**

```
int flag = 0;
try{
        img_car.setImageURI(Uri.parse(path_picture));
        flag = 1;
    }catch(Throwable e){ 

        img_car.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_car);
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, no change, the same thing.

Comment: change is here catch(Throwable e)

Comment: Yes, I have tried your version, I mean is no change in the app.

Answer (score 0):

[@AlexAndro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1018387/alexandro)'s answer works in major cases, you can use it. But in some specific situations, kinda the URI has weird path inside, it doesn't work.

So, there is a code which works the same way correctly:

```
imageView.setImageURI(imageUri)
if (imageView.drawable==null) {
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_default)
}
```

I realized the problem during working at music player application. When I get information about all the songs from device, I usually get some strage image URIs with each song. Their path is so strange, kinda **/external/audio/albumart/2** . Obviously, ImageView cannot recognize this URI. And in my case only the code above has helped me.

P.S. It must be a common problem! This topic is soo ancient, isn't it?